# Tracking a one subdomains on two top-level domains

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to track one subdomain, that has two top-level domains pointing to it. For example:

my.test.com
my.test.org

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'test.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I've found this piece of code along with information about filters for multiple subdomains, but I'm not sure how that would work with two top-level domains. The example shows `_setDomainName` as a specific top-level domain. How would I go about making this work with two top-level domains?

Comment: What you are looking for is cross domain tracking.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to set up cross domain tracking. What you are currently "missing" is actually linking together your two domains through `_link` calls.

As detailed on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains, you need to add an argument to any links pointing to the links between the two domains.

What this effectively does is allowing Google Analytics to copy cookie data between top-level domains.

Links on my.test.com should `_link` to my.test.org, and vice versa.

Example: `<a href="http://my.test.org/" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link','http://my.test.org/']); return false;">Anchortext to my.test.org</a>`

If post is used to transfer visitors, you can find instructions on the above URL for that as well.